# creating zip distribution with different files in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build, zip, build.gradle

I am currently exporting a zip distribution from my `gradle` project and trying to add some more files in it **but unable to place them in the desired location**.

here is the structure of my project

```
TestProj/source
        /export_dir / A1
                    / B1
                    / C1 / data / results.txt
        /resources/temp.txt
        /build.gradle
```

I was using the `gradle Zip` task to export the **export_dir as .zip file like below**.

```
task exportZIP(type: Zip) {
    from 'export_dir'
}
```

and it exports the `export_dir` in TestProj-v1.zip but now i want to export temp.txt within the export_dir directory. so the **resultant zip file should look like this**

```
/export_dir / A1
            / B1
            / C1 / data / results.txt
                        / temp.txt
```

I have tried the task below to do this **but it is copying the temp.txt in the root of the zip not inside the desired place in the zip**.

```
task exportZIP(type: Zip) {
    from 'export_dir'
    from 'resources/temp.txt'
    into('export_dir/C1/data') {
    }
}
```

any help or suggestion on how can i achieve this.

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying `temp.txt` in `export_dir/C1/data/` inside the zip, I took a different approach as a fix.

I wrote the gradle task to copy the temp.txt in `export_dir/C1/data/` inside the `TestProj` directory so that when i export the zip of `export_dir` it should have temp.txt already present at the right place.

Here is what i used

```
task copyTempToExpo(type: Copy) {
    from 'resources/temp.txt'
}
```

and then export the zip of only `export_dir`

```
task exportZIP(type: Zip) {
    from 'export_dir'
}
```

and then delete the temp.txt from `resources` directory.

```
task clearTemp(type: Delete) {
  delete "resources/temp.txt";
}
```

But i m still interested in knowing if there is some other way (like what i asked in question itself) to do this job.